# TCP buffering deadlock, how can i disconnect a user who isn't receiving data?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, buffering

I have a server that runs fine except when I performance test it by spamming packets through it. The clients do not receive data only send and then the server ends up in a deadlock.

How can I check if the end user is not receiving data and disconnect them accordingly does it trigger some type of error that I can work off?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Beej's guide](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sendman.html) is a great reference to sockets. Depending on your needs, you can use the value of `errno` if a call like `send(socket, buffer, buffer_length, MSG_DONTWAIT);` is made and returns `-1`. `errno` having a value of `EAGAIN` indicates that the buffer handling the out traffic is currently full.

One question to ask is if your clients are actually the ones getting filled up. Is your server's buffer not able to be emptied faster than what you're trying to write?

@EJB has a good point that my question could be somewhat meaningless, because in most cases, the reason for `errno` having the value `EAGAIN` during a `send` is that the client isn't keeping up with the transfer. In that case, you'd simply `close(client_socket);` and be done with that specific client. If you are wanting something more advanced, you should create some sort of algorithm that will use a set of heuristics to determine the state of such client, and handle accordingly instead of simply dropping the connection, unless that's what you're really wanting.

A very basic example heuristic you could use is to give each client an allotted time until they're considered unresponsive. For example, if you keep getting `EAGAIN` on the same client for the next 5-10 seconds, that client could be considered unresponsive and you could close the connection.

Comment: Your question is meaningless. The server buffer can only be emptied at the same rate as the client buffer.

Comment: Not necessarily. There are a lot of variables involved, however it could be that my question is more unlikely than other cases.

Comment: "the client isn't keeping up with the transfer" So close the connection. That is exactly what I am trying to do :) Thank you. I will try this when I get home.